# Como acessar o conteúdo de um elemento iframe?

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
description = document.getElementsByClassName('rte-container')[0]
description = description.lastChild.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
```

Isso me retorna este elemento:

```
<iframe id="mce_17_ifr" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" title="Rich Text Area. Press ALT-0 for help." class="tox-edit-area__iframe"></iframe>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para selecionar os elementos dentro de **">#document"** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você deve ter percebido, o iframe tem um `document` separado. Ele é outra janela e possui outro documento. Você precisa de algo [nesta linha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926916/how-to-get-the-bodys-content-of-an-iframe-in-javascript):

```
var iframeDocument = description.contentDocument || description.contentWindow.document;
```

Com isso consegue acessar normalmente o que precisar nesse document, opr exemplo:

```
var body = iframeDocument.querySelector('body');
```

> **IMPORTANTE**
> O conteúdo do iframe precisa ser do mesmo domínio do seu documento, caso contrário uma restrição de segurança (CORS) impedirá o acesso ao DOM do iframe.